# How to show notification bar in Android emulator

Tags: android, notifications, emulation

I know it sounds very basic and maybe stupid, but I'm stuck on trying to "pull down" the notification bar in Android emulator. How we do it using the mouse or keyboard??

I'm developing my first app and I've always used a real device, but now I'm trying to use the emulator as well.

PS.: yes, I've searched a lot everywhere!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe:

*To see the details of the notification, you will have to select the icon which will display notification drawer having detail about the notification. While working with emulator with virtual device, you will have to click and drag down the status bar to expand it which will give you detail as follows. This will be just 64 dp tall and called normal view.*

Refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm for more details.

Comment: Solution (SOF innacurate policies avoided me of creating an answer so I'm writing it as a comment here):

Well, I solved the issue by editing my virtual device (AVD) by setting it as a Nexus One (it can probably be any other brand/model). The point is that my AVD was kinda of "basic", so for some (stupid?) reason it didn't come with the notification bar, so it wasn't possible the pull the notification down.

That's it, after struggling a lot over boring Eclipse updates. Now I can test my app's notifications fine! Thanks user2515563, I hope this question/solution can help other people too!

Answer (score 1):

I had to select the notification drawer from as close to the window bar as possible.